# Is there a full example for a Cloudinary + Django Upload out there?

Tags: jquery, django, cloudinary

The Cloudinary + Django documentation is very sparse for a novice such as myself and I keep running up against roadblocks. Has anyone seen or know of some example code I can checkout for doing file uploads? Especially with regard to the jQuery plugin which claims to be based of an existing jQuery plugin, but with no documentation as to how it differs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some Django code snippets in [this blog post](http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery), which describes how to do direct uploads from the browser to Cloudinary using a jQuery plugin.
Regardless, we are working on improving our documentation and providing comprehensive sample projects.

**UPDATE**

A full Django sample code is available. Including server-side uploading as well as direct uploading from the browser.

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-django-sample